# Javascript code refactor to use in Stimulus controller

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, validation, refactoring, stimulusjs

How to refactor JS code like this:

```
const fileInput = document.getElementById('input');
const p = document.querySelector('p');
fileInput.onchange = () => {
  const selectedFiles = [...fileInput.files];
  p.textContent = selectedFiles.map(s => s.size).join(', ');
}
```

to make it work in rail's Stimulus?
I have very little experience with JS and want to have one or two examples of implementing JS code in Stimulus controllers, so I have material to refactor other cases on my own.
Much thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution:

```html
<div data-controller="file">
  <input type="file" data-file-target="input" data-action="change->file#displayText" id="my-input">
  <output data-file-target="text" for="my-input"></output>
</div>
```

```js
// filename_controller.js

// Connects to data-controller="file"
export default class extends Controller {
  static targets = ["input", "text"]
  
  displayText() {
    const selectedFiles = [...thisInputTarget.files];
    this.textTarget.textContent = selectedFiles.map(s => s.size).join(', ');
  }
}
```

Comment: One tip. When using input fields - you can skip the event name part. ata-action="file#displayText" - this will also work.  https://stimulus.hotwired.dev/reference/actions#descriptors